# Most efficient way to get the content from a tag and save it in a variable in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code in vue

```
<ul>
      <li v-for="exchange in finalExchanges"><button class="resultBtn"> {{exchange}} <hr></button></li>
</ul>
```

With the following js

```
export default {
name: 'exchange',
data () {
  return {
    exchanges,
    msg: 'Exchange',
    search: ''
  }
},
computed: {
finalExchanges() {
  return this.exchanges.filter(exchange => {
    return exchange.includes(this.search)
   })
  }
 }
}
```

I'm curious to know what is the most efficient way to get the {{exchange}} that user clicks on and save it in a variable. I presume that there are a lot of ways like using document.getElementById() and probably a vue way too but I'm looking for an efficient way to do this considering how future-proof it is. Any opinion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had some variable in your data like maybe "selectedExchange" and you wanted to assign the clicked exchange to that variable you could simply add to your button:

```
<button @click="selectedExchange = exchange"...>
```

If I understand the problem correctly this is certainly the most common and probably the most efficient way to get the clicked exchange.

If you wanted to use the clicked exchange as a variable in a method you would simply put:

```
<button @click="someFunction(exchange)"...>
```

And then you'd just get it in your method like:

```
...
methods: {
  someFunction: function( ex ) {
    ... // ex will be the clicked exchange
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this solution.
At first add currentExchange variable in data if you need to store it

```
data () {
 return {
  exchanges,
  msg: 'Exchange',
  search: '',
  currentExchange: null
}
```

}

Then add event handler, in your button where you pass current exchangeValue

```
<button class="resultBtn" v-on:click="handlerFunc(exchange)"> {{exchange}}<hr></button>
```

Please have in mind that `v-on:click` might be replaced as `@click`

Now in your handler do your logic

```
methods:{
handlerFunc(exchange) {
  // assign it to data if needed
  this.currentExchange = exchange
  // do your stuff...
}
```

Comment: his method looks simpler but yours doesn't seem that much different than his, I already implemented his feature but can you tell me why do you think your solution is better than his?